porque no me toma la carga a mi LocalStorage? React JS
en el siguiente codigo, la funcion handleAddLS esta tomando el id de la subcategoria que se seleccionó para poder reflejarlo en la pagina a la cual me va a redirigir, utilizando dicha informacion para un filtrado de productos
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainSubCategoria = () => {
    const [subcategorias, setSubcategorias] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("Musculacion");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDataSub = async () => {
            const subcategoriasSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'categoMarca'));
            const subcategoriasData = subcategoriasSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
            setSubcategorias(subcategoriasData);
        }
        fetchDataSub();
    }, [])

    const handleAddLS = (subcategoriaId) => {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedSubcategoria', subcategoriaId);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            {selectedCategory === "Musculacion" && (
                <div className="mainSubCateg">
                    <h1 className="tituloMainSubCateg">Categoría: {selectedCategory}</h1>
                    <div>
                        <h2 className="subtituloMainSubCateg">Subcategorías:</h2>
                        <div className="row containerImgSubCatego">
                            {subcategorias.map(subcategoria => (
                                <Link
                                    key={subcategoria.id}
                                    onClick={() => handleAddLS(subcategoria.id)}
                                    className="imgLinkSubCatego col-md-3 col-12"
                                    to={`/Catalogo`}
                                >
                                    <div className="imgBoxSubCatego">
                                        <img className="imgSubCatego" src={subcategoria.imagen} alt="" />
                                        <p className="textMainSubCatego">
                                            {subcategoria.nombre}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </Link>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MainSubCategoria;

el cual quiero que se refleje en mi siguiente codigo, pero no me lo toma como deberia tomarlo  y aplicarse de forma correcta, no logro ver en que me estoy equivocando si alguien puede aconsejarme
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import ProductList from '../components/Products/ProductList';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import SearchBar from "../components/Search/SearchBar";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faClose } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import Navbarr from "../components/NavCatego/NavBar1";
import Offcanvas from "react-bootstrap/Offcanvas";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import CategoryButtons from "../components/NavCatego/CategoryButtons";
import { faWhatsapp } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import Navbarr1 from '../components/NavCatego/NavBar1';


const Cart = () => {
    const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState("todos");
    const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState("todos");
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    /*     const [datosIng, setDatosIng] = useState([]); */
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    /*     const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false); */
    const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const locParam = urlParams.get("loc");

    const getProducts = async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'productos'));
        return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const datas = await getProducts();
            console.log(datas)
            setData(datas);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            setDataLoaded(true);
        }
    }, [data]);

    const getCategoriaProductos = async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'categorias'));
        return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, nombre: doc.data().nombre }));
    };
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCategories = async () => {
            const categorias = await getCategoriaProductos();
            setCategoria(categorias);
        };
        fetchCategories();
    }, []);



    const searchProducts = (term) => {
        const results = term
            ? data.filter((product) =>
                product.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
            )
            : data;
        setSearchResults(results);
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        if (dataLoaded) {
            searchProducts(searchTerm);
        }
    }, [dataLoaded, searchTerm]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dataLoaded) {
            searchProducts("");
        }
    }, [dataLoaded]);

    const handleSearchTermChange = (event) => {
        const term = event.target.value;
        setSearchTerm(term);
    };
    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setMenuOpen((menuOpen) => !menuOpen);
    };


    const handleTypeChange = (type) => {
        setSelectedType(type);
        if (menuOpen) {
            setMenuOpen(false);
        }
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(localStorage.getItem('selectedSubcategoria')!== '' ){
            handleTypeChange(localStorage.getItem('selectedSubcategoria'));
            setTimeout(() => {
                localStorage.removeItem('selectedSubcategoria');
            }, 2000);
        }
    }, []);



    const menuRef = useRef(null);

    const handleOptionClickFl = () => {
        setSelectedFilter("todos");
    };

    const handleBorrarSearch = () => {
        setSearchTerm("");
    };

    return (
        <div className="contMain1">
            <Navbar />
            {
                <Offcanvas show={menuOpen} onHide={toggleMenu} placement="end">
                    {
                        <div className={`row cart-overlay`}>
                            <div className={`col-12 cart-container`}>
                                <div ref={menuRef} className="contCart">
                                    <div
                                        style={{
                                            display: "flex",
                                            justifyContent: "right",
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <div
                                            style={{
                                                display: "flex",
                                                justifyContent: "center",
                                                width: "30px",
                                                height: "20px",
                                                position: "relative",
                                                cursor: "pointer",
                                                top: "5px",
                                            }}
                                            type="button"
                                            onClick={toggleMenu}
                                        >
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClose} className="iconX" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <CategoryButtons
                                            categories={categoria}
                                            selectedType={selectedType}
                                            handleTypeChange={handleTypeChange}
                                            handleFilterChange={setSelectedFilter}
                                            setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </Offcanvas>
            }
            <div
                className="contenedorSearchBar"
                style={{ paddingRight: "0%", marginRight: "0%", width: "100%" }}
            >
                <div>
                    <div
                        className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 col-xl-12 contSearchBar"
                        style={{
                            paddingRight: "0%",
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                        }}
                    >
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                handleTypeChange("todos");
                                handleOptionClickFl("borrar-filtros");
                                handleBorrarSearch("");
                            }}
                            className="txtBorrarFil"
                        >
                            <h6>Borrar Filtros</h6>
                        </button>
                        <SearchBar
                            searchTerm={searchTerm}
                            handleSearchTermChange={handleSearchTermChange}
                        />
                        <div className="contFilter">
                            <Navbarr1
                                menuOpen={menuOpen}
                                toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
                                selectedType={selectedType}
                                handleTypeChange={handleTypeChange}
                                handleFilterChange={setSelectedFilter}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4 className='tresYSeis'>
                        3 y 6 Cuotas sin Interés con Macro
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                className="row"
                style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
            >
                <div className="col-md-2 col-3 contBtnsFilter">
                    <div>
                        <Navbarr className="filtroPantallaGrande"
                            menuOpen={menuOpen}
                            toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
                            selectedType={selectedType}
                            handleTypeChange={handleTypeChange}
                            handleFilterChange={setSelectedFilter}
                        />
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                handleTypeChange("todos");
                                handleOptionClickFl("borrar-filtros");
                                handleBorrarSearch("");
                            }}
                            className="txtBorrarFilDos"
                        >
                            <span>Borrar Filtros</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10 col-9 containerProductsPrincipal">
                    <ProductList
                        searchResults={searchResults}
                        selectedType={selectedType}
                        selectedFilter={selectedFilter}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <section className='loguitoWSP'>
                <a className='iconoWspMain' href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=5493572448243&text=Hola!+Te+quiero+hacer+una+consulta+sobre+tu+servicio...&type=phone_number&app_absent=0" target='blank'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className='wspLink' icon={faWhatsapp} />
                </a>
            </section>

            <Footer />
        </div >
    );
};

export default Cart;

en la funcion handleTypeChange es donde yo obtengo mi localStorage nuevamente para sacar los datos de la subcategoria que necesito para el filtrado y luego lo elimino por el simple hecho de que lo necesito solamente para ese instante

Bienvenido a la comunidad, Parece un problema de sincronización de los efectos que llaman a localStorage, ¿Cual es el orden en el que llamas a Cart y MainSubCategoria? Explica como es la comunicación entre ambos componentes, agrega esa info a la pregunta, puedes editarla.
